# MS Teams Error message: Failed to retrieve flag from thread properties. Conversation not found

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am developing azure bot using python sdk v4. From yesterday, this bot is giving below error when i opened personal teams chat with bot on browser

```
2022-04-12T11:42:47.992Z ConversationsServiceHelper: getChatConversation(): 28:a2146824-9e29-4eff-b4c2-ba6f24c7e235 not found


2022-04-12T11:42:48.123Z meetingCoachService retrieve meetingObjectsConfig failed (threadId 28:a2146824-9e29-4eff-b4c2-ba6f24c7e235, messageId undefined). Error message: Failed to retrieve flag from thread properties. Conversation not found.
```

Comment: Can anyone help on above issue?

Comment: Could you please share repro steps?

Comment: Hi, this bot can work as echo bot. When I opened ms teams in chrome browser with browser console opened then after opening of  personal chat with my bot then type anything(like "Hi Bot"). In the browser console above two error messages listed.

Comment: When you say a "personal" Teams chat, do you mean a personal tenant, or do you mean a 1 on 1 chat with the bot?


Additionally, what do you mean by "can work as an echo bot"? Did you just deploy the sample/template echo bot? Did you upload an app manifest to Teams?

Comment: It is 1 on 1 chat with bot. I am using on_message_activity method which returns back messages i type during chat with bot. Yes, I have uploaded app in zip format to Teams during testing of this bot.

Comment: I'd recommend you check out the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) and see if the Teams samples help. If not, you might want to consider updating your question with repro steps and code samples so that people can try to help you.

Comment: @Raj - Could you please confirm if the above suggestion helped you in any way or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Another similar question was resolved by fixing firewall rules. Perhaps you should check yours.

Comment: @Raj - Could you please confirm if the above suggestion helped you in any way or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Yes, above suggestion helped. Fixing firewall rules did the job.

Comment: What firewall rule was blocking the conversation?